# Get high-order block's id on click

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I have a high-order block and a nested block inside of it. I expect to get the `parent`'s `id` on click, but its `child` appears to be an event target.

How can I make JS consider a `parent` to be an event target or get its `id` somehow else.

- I cannot specify the needed DOM block explicitly (`e.g. document.getElementById(...)`), because they are displayed dynamically.
- `parent` may be not a direct parent of a `child`

```js
function saveID(e) {
  const display = document.getElementById("display");

  if (e.target.id) {
    display.innerHTML = (`Parent's key is: ${e.target.id}`);
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = "Won't happen";
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.child:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-color: green;
}

#display {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 83px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="1" onclick="saveID()">
  <div class="child">
    Hey there!
  </div>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `currentTarget` instead on target, as it gives the element on which the `onclick` event is defined

```
function saveID(e) {
  const display = document.getElementById("display");

  if (e.currentTarget.id) {
    display.innerHTML = (`Parent's key is: ${e.target.id}`);
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = "Won't happen";
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! It worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parent id on click of the child , add the onclick to the child, and `e.target.parentNode.id` to get the parent id

```js
function saveID(e) {
  const display = document.getElementById("display");

  if (e.target.id) {
    display.innerHTML = (`Parent's key is: ${e.target.parentNode.id}`);
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = "Won't happen";
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.child:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-color: green;
}

#display {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 83px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="1">
  <div class="child" id="child" onclick="saveID(event)">
    Hey there!
  </div>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

get the id  Attribute  value from classname

```js
function saveID() {
  const display = document.getElementById("display");
  var res  = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].getAttribute('id');

//get the id  Attribute  value from classname 

  if (res) {
    display.innerHTML = (`Parent's key is: ${res}`);
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = "Won't happen";
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.child:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-color: green;
}

#display {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 83px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="1" onclick="saveID()">
  <div class="child">
    Hey there!
  </div>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```